# how to retrieve login cookie (PHP)

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

Hi I have a textbox that takes a username input. When the user submits the form, a cookie is created that stores the time of the cookie. On the next page, I need to display the time they were last logged in. How can I do this using the following cookie code?

```
SETCOOKIE($_POST['name'], time(), time() + 60*60*24*30);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the users name everytime or save it in the server which is probably not the best solution here.. Why dont you have  a static cookie name and do something like this when he logs in:

```
SETCOOKIE('LASTLOGGEDINTIME', time(), time() + 60*60*24*30);
```

`$_COOKIE['LASTLOGGEDINTIME']` should retrieve the value.. do the necessary null/empty checks

Comment: If I have a static cookie name, then how would each time be linked to each user?

Comment: Cookies are stored by each user's browser. On page request you will only get one user's cookies.

Comment: so even if i have multiple users, I can only store one cookie?

Comment: Ok I get it. But whenever the user logs back in. The time of the cookie gets set again. So when I retrieve it, it is the current time. Rather than when they first logged in

Comment: then only set it, if it is not present. `if (!isset($_COOKIE['LASTLOGGEDINTIME'])) setcookie(...);` or even better, set it when you actually do the login.